# Reactive boxplot in Shiny with interactive mean line

Tags: r, shiny, boxplot, reactive

I'm new to R and have been trying some stuff out. Now I want to make a rather simple shiny app with the purpose of asking some question about a Dataset I found at keggle. The dataset regards salaries in San Francisco.

My idea is as follows:

Create a boxplot as in:

> Categories <- cut(Salaries$TotalPay, breaks = c(0,30000,60000,100000,500000), labels=c("low","mid","high","highest"))
>   boxplot(TotalPay~Categories)

I'd like for a user to select which of these, or all of these he/she wants to see.

Currently I've got:

**UI:**

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(


  headerPanel("Miles Per Gallon"),

  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("variable", "Variable:",
                list("Low" = "low", 
                     "Mid" = "mid", 
                     "High" = "high",
                     "Highest"= "highest")),

  mainPanel(
    h3(textOutput("caption")),

    plotOutput("Plot")
  )
)
  )
)
```

**Server:**

```
library(shiny)

Categories <- cut(Salaries$TotalPay, breaks = c(0,30000,60000,100000,500000), labels=c("low","mid","high","highest"))

shinyServer(function(input, output) {


  formulaText <- reactive({
    paste("TotalPay~", input$variable)
  })

  output$caption <- renderText({
    formulaText()
  })


  Plot <- renderPlot({
    boxplot(as.formula(formulaText()), 
            data = Categories
            )
  })
})
```

What am I doing wrong? I think it's issues with importing the data from "Salaries".

Thanks in advance :).

Comment: I don't see any function where you are loading your data...

Comment: Yea it's one of my issues. I've been trying to with the library function but it didnt work. How should I?

Comment: Library is only used to load packages. Do you have your data in a csv file?

Comment: Yea, its Salaries.csv, do i use  read.csv()  in the top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify on my comment, you use libary() to load packages, but those packages may be data sets from CRAN or base R. But for your example, you need something like this in your server.r file:

```
salaries <- read.csv("Salaries.csv")
```

Make sure that csv file is in the same folder as your ui.r and server.r files

Since you are new to R and shiny, this example app may help with using ui widgets:
https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/telephones-by-region.html

Note that the above example uses the data set that is in the "datasets" library.

**EDIT:**

I noticed some other items that raise some other questions. Are you deploying this app on Shiny Server? Your server function is using ShinyServer when I think it needs to be more like this:

```
server <- function(input, output) { 
#server code

shinyApp(ui= ui, server = server)
}
```

And your ui should be more like this:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
#ui code
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex! So were I to read it. Would it do what I want it to do to your knowledge?

Comment: Since the data is from kaggle, if you send it to me I may be able to get it working for you.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Your advice has helped a tonne.

Comment: If this answer solves your problem then will you approve it as the accepted answer?

Comment: It has mostly, thanks, I was way of without it! Accepted it as a solution.